# Problems when trying to re-access a remote computer with Teamviewer when a previous connection has been lost

Tags: windows-7, networking, remote-desktop, tv, teamviewer

I have two computers, Windows 7 Pro x64: HomeComputer; WorkComputer, both have TeamViewer 10 installed.

On each machine, TV is configured to allow unattended access, this works most of the time. I can connect to my work computer from my home computer and vice versa. I can also close an established connection (i. e. I can manually quit TV) and re-access to the remote computer again and again... No problem!

**My problem (example):**
If I leave my HomeComputer (which, *let's say for the leave moment*, has an active TV-connection to my WorkComputer) it will automatically enter Sleep mode after a while. Of course the active TV connection automatically will also be closed.

When I wake my HomeComputer up again, and try to re-access my WorkComputer again, this dialog is what I meet:

[image: Please wait for our partner to confirm the request]

Has anybody seen this behavior? Both of my computers have TV configured to allow unattended access but the latter seems only to work if there hasn't been a previously (accidentally) lost connection.

How should I configure TV to always allow unattended access even if any connection is lost?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you can try install-

> TeamViewer Host

using this service, you can access your remote computers when its login/logout etc..

Comment: I have installed [TeamViewer full version - Windows](http://www.teamviewer.com/en/download/windows.aspx) (free). My current configuration will start TeamViewer with Windows, I also have it set to accept unattended access (please see my original question). Anyway, i thought my configuration acted as a host already? What do you mean with "install TeamViewer Host"?